# When replacing fragment inside a RecyclerView item : "No view found for id" of container

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having trouble referencing the Container "youtube_fragmento" inside the ViewHolders

My idea is to make a RecyclerView with viewHolders that switches between YoutubePlayerFragment and a PreviewFragment(by changing the fragment inside a container) , 
activating only the YoutubeVideoPlayerFragment of the video clicked

Fragment where is put the RecyclerView :

```
    public class CanalesFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "2";
ListView lvVideo;
String searchName;
String TAG="ChannelActivity";
String URL="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC9CYT9gSNLevX5ey2_6CK0Q&maxResults=25&key="+YoutubeConfig.getApiKey();

private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;
private static CanalesRecyclerAdapter canalesRecyclerAdapter;
public static ArrayList<video> videos;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public CanalesFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static CanalesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    CanalesFragment fragment = new CanalesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_canales, container, false);

    videos = new ArrayList<video>();
    videoParser.getVideosFromUrl(URL);

 RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCanales);
 canalesRecyclerAdapter = new CanalesRecyclerAdapter(getContext(),getActivity(), 
 this.getChildFragmentManager(),videos);

 canalesRecyclerAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new 
CanalesRecyclerAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(FrameLayout b, View view, video obj, int position) 
{//custom made method to input a ClickListener to the adapter
    for (int i = 0; i < videos.size(); i++) { //when one video is clicked i set them all to PreviewFragment
        videos.get(i).reproduciendo=false;
    }
    canalesRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    videos.get(position).reproduciendo=true;   //then change to 
YoutubePlayerFragment at the one clicked
    canalesRecyclerAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(canalesRecyclerAdapter);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    return v;


}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

public static void updateRecyclerView(){
    canalesRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
}
```

this is the RecyclerAdapter :

```
public class CanalesRecyclerAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {


@NonNull
Context context;
Activity activity;
private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;
ArrayList<video> videos;
private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private FragmentManager childFragmentManager;
final private int HACK_ID_PREFIX = 12345678; //preset number to generate IDs

public CanalesRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Activity activity, 
FragmentManager childFragmentManager, ArrayList<video> videos) {
    this.context = context;
    this.videos = videos;
    this.activity=activity;
    this.childFragmentManager = childFragmentManager;
    this.mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
}
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(FrameLayout b , View view, video obj, int position);

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
    this.mOnItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemyoutube, viewGroup, false);
    videoItem item = new videoItem(row,context,videos);


    return item;



}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

    bindVideo((videoItem)viewHolder, i);

    final video s = videos.get(i);
    if(videos.get(i).reproduciendo){ //if this video is the one that should play

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(HACK_ID_PREFIX+i,  youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener OIL = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                youTubePlayer.loadVideo(videos.get(i).videoID);
                youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaying() {

                        youTubePlayer.seekToMillis(0);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPaused() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStopped() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onBuffering(boolean b) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSeekTo(int i) {

                    }
                });


            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        };
        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeConfig.getApiKey(), OIL);

    }else{ //if its not playing we replace container with a Preview

        FragmentTransaction transaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
         videoPreviewFragment frag = videoPreviewFragment.newInstance(videos.get(i).videoID,"");


        transaction.replace(HACK_ID_PREFIX+i,frag).commit();


    }

    ((videoItem) viewHolder).youtubeVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) { 
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(((videoItem) viewHolder).youtubeVideo,v, s, i);
            }
        }
    });


           }

private void bindVideo(final videoItem viewHolder, int i) { //para darle un tag al momento de asignar el video
    View view = viewHolder.itemView.findViewWithTag("video_container");
    if (view != null) {

        Log.e("idGenerado", String.valueOf(HACK_ID_PREFIX+i));
        view.setId(HACK_ID_PREFIX + i);
    }
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return videos.size();
}

}

class videoItem extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
FrameLayout  youtubeVideo;
ArrayList<video> videos = new ArrayList<video>();
Context context;

public videoItem(View itemView, Context context, ArrayList<video> videos) {
    super(itemView);
    this.videos = videos;
    this.context = context;

    youtubeVideo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_fragmento);

}}
```

The layout from item_youtube , inflated for a viewHolder :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="260dp"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_fragmento"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:tag="video_container"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</FrameLayout>
```

When i put on a onBindViewHolder, with the code below, a fragment inside the container, it always replaces in the Container[R.id.youtube_fragmento] of the first RecyclerView item :

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
  transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragmento, 
youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
```

Apparently in this case its giving for container [R.id.youtube_fragmento] the same ID for every viewHolder,

so i opted to give each container an own ID (with bindVideo() function) setting a custom ID to the container depending on the position

It's working for the first 3 viewHolders(the ones that fit the first drawn screen) , but after scrolling to see more, i get this error, being the ID "0xbc6151" the ID set with bindVideo() to the 4th viewHolder container

Error : " 
Invalid ID 0x00bc6151.
 No view found for id 0xbc6151 (unknown) for fragment videoPreviewFragment{32586d8 #25 id=0xbc6151} "

I also tried setting viewHolder.isRecyclable(false) to check if recycling is giving me problems with custom IDs and the problem is still there

Comment: why dont you use a fragment that is [added in xml](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating#AddInLayout)?

Comment: i have to switch the fragment(between preview/video) inside the container programatically depending on which one is selected

Comment: so use different view types: see `Adapter#getItemViewType()` method

Comment: can ItemViewType be changed on the run and redrawn in an onClick ?
i'll be trying that out

Comment: you can return anything from `getItemViewType` so... use `notifyItemChanged` for `getItemViewType` to be re-called